# Php working on localhost but not on live website

Tags: php, mysqli

**This is my code and the php only works on a local host**

Im trying to get it to work on our website for a group project, I have neverused php  before so I am fairly new to it.

```
<?php
$servername= "sql5.freemysqlhosting.net:3306";
$username="sql5404117";
$password="******";
$dbname="sql5404117";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if($mysqli === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
$query = "SELECT * FROM David";
if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Album Number</th>";
                echo "<th>Song</th>";
                echo "<th>Artist</th>";
                echo "<th>Album</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['V1'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['V2'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['V3'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['V4'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $query. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Port name is the 5th parameter, not part of host name. `new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306)`

Comment: Check your php version of live server i think it will be too old or inherited so kindly select a proper version of php .

Comment: Could you please provide an error message and/or tell us what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$servername = "localhost";
```

instead of

```
$servername= "sql5.freemysqlhosting.net:3306";
```

unless if you are connecting to an external server in which case you would explicitly name it's public address.

Also, as mentioned in the comments by @user3783243, *port* is the 5th parameter in the [mysqli::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), so in case you need to speciify it you would do it like this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);
```

**Note:** 3306 is usually the default MySQL port so it usually doesn't have to be specified.